# is openjdk complete opensource implementation of java along with jvm and compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, jvm, java

does OpenJdk provide complete opensource implementation for java along with JVM and compiler sources, so that it can be modified by others and implement to distribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OpenJDK is the [Reference Implementation](https://jdk8.java.net/java-se-8-ri/) of Java SE.
It includes JVM, Class Library, tools etc.

The modification and distribution is subject to [GNU General Public License, version 2 with the Classpath Exception](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html).

Comment: Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies of this license
document, but changing it is not allowed.<-- What does it mean in documentation??

Comment: @vinaybayyaram This means the license cannot be changed. Any work derived from GPLv2-licensed software must be also released under the same GPLv2 terms.

Comment: "changing it is not allowed" refers to the fact that you can't change the license itself. That is, you can't take the license itself and change the terms (like you can with software licensed under the GPL). You have to use the GPL license as is, or you can choose not to use the license - that means not using the software or convincing the copyright owner to license it under another license.

Comment: This answer isn't true. OpenJDK is licensed under a more complex license. As the link itself says, it's the "GNU General Public License, version 2, with the Classpath Exception". The last bit is important. I am not a lawyer, but the exception makes it much closer to the LGPL than pure GPL. It generally means that if you use openjdk, you don't have to release the source of your own software - like you would have to if OpenJDK was pure GPL. Again, IANAL.